# How can i write a script (to automate this process) that find spaces and special character in file name. I have large data of filename in SVN

Tags: bash, shell

find.-type f|egrep-i"~||&|@|#|<|>|;|:|!|'^'|,|-|_"|tee temp.txt

I am not sure about special characters like * or $. Can you help me out with this.

Comment: Thoses lines do the work ?

Comment: You can strip that `-name '*'` because it is a filter which will let _everything_ pass.  So you can leave it away.  Maybe instead you should use it to find the files containing a bad character:  `find . -name '*,*' -exec rename \, '' {} \;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I'd suggest to write a script which takes a single file name and fixes it. Then you can do:

```
find . -type f -exec /path/to/fixNames.sh "{}" \;
```

`fixNames.sh` could then contain:

```
rename 's/[ \t]/-/' "$1" # blanks
rename "s/'\",//" "$1" # characters to remove
rename 's/&/-n-/' "$1"
```

Note: Test this with a folder with some bad file names! Only run this against the real files when you know that this doesn't cause problems!

Related:

- [Introduction to shell scripting](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/)

Comment: I am trying to write the script to automate it and i m new with that so If you can give me some example on how should i write it

Comment: I suggest to read http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/ which gives a good introduction to shell scripting.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. this script link is very helpfull to undersatnd.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting up two arrays - one for the special characters, one for the replacements (they should contain the same number of indexes)?

```
#!/bin/bash

SPECIALCHARS=("," " " "&" "\\" "\"")
REPLACEMENTS=("" "-" "-n-" "" "")

for i in $(seq 0 $((${#SPECIALCHARS[@]}-1))); do 
    find . -exec rename "${SPECIALCHARS[$i]}" "${REPLACEMENTS[$i]}" {} \;  
done
```

Comment: I am trying to write the script to automate it and i m new with that so If you can give me some example on how should i write it