# I want to find all the file names present in SVN that contain spaces and special characters

Tags: shell, unix, svn

I want to find all the file names present in SVN that contain spaces and special characters and put them in `temp.txt`. I don't have a path for that. I need to find file names in subfolders as well.

I tried the following command, but it is not working.

```
find.-type f|egrep-i"~||&|@|#|<|>|;|:|!|'^'|,|-|_"|tee temp.txt
```

What is it doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i write a script (to automate this process) that find spaces and special character in file name. I have large data of filename in SVN](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21991115/how-can-i-write-a-script-to-automate-this-process-that-find-spaces-and-special)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're regex is wrong. Try this:

```
find . -type f | egrep -i "[-~&@#<>;:!^,_]" | tee temp.txt
```

You want to specify the characters to find and that is just what `[]` is for. I may have missed a few characters you meant, so double check I included them all.

Also note that this command will find *any* file in the directory - it may or may not be part of the repo.

Comment: This is not taking. Gives an error: -ksh: find.-type: not found

Comment: Works in bash, I can't speak to ksh. Edit to match as you had in OP.