# Why does my script hang when I try to run it?

Tags: perl

I am trying to find the file names that contain non-alphanumeric characters in the output of:

```
svn ls -R url
```

I wrote the following Perl script to do this:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl -w

while (<>) {
    s|/$||;
    s|^|code/|;
    if (!m|.*(/[-./\w]+?$)|) {
        print "$_";
    }
 }
```

I run the following commands in my shell:

```
svn ls -R url
./script
```

but my terminal hangs after the `./script` command. Why?

Comment: So, you're trying to find the paths returned by `svn ls` where the file name contains non-alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Why did you [delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22102770/i-create-a-script-that-find-a-space-and-specialcharacter-in-file-name-but-having) and reask your question? Ah, you've got a [history](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22076350/i-want-to-find-all-the-file-names-present-in-svn-which-contains-spaces-and-spec) of this. Please don't do that, it's rude.

Comment: Sure, I will make sure for naxt time. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am trying to do the same way.

Comment: What issue are you having with your current script?

Comment: I am not sure but its not going through. May be i m doing something wrong with it like putting at wrong place

Comment: What do you mean "not going through"? Do you get an error? If so, what is it? Does your terminal hang? What is the *exact* command you ran on the command line? Don't make people guess what you're doing; be specific.

Comment: Terminal gets hang. First i run svn ls -R projects url and then i got list of files and then run this script as ./script.sh and terminal gets hang.

Comment: It hangs because it's waiting for input from `stdin`. Instead, do: `svn ls -R url | ./script` (by the way, this is a Perl script so you shouldn't name it `script.sh`; `.sh` is generally used for shell scripts)

Comment: ohh. So what would be the name ? is is .pl ?

Comment: On *nix you don't need an extension, just `myscript` is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is waiting for input on `stdin`. Pipe the results of `svn ls` to your script like this:

```
svn ls -R url | ./script
```